# Magento: MySql show slow query with missing index

Tags: mysql, performance, magento, entity-attribute-value

I'm checking for performance issue with Magento 1.8.1, I've enabled the following MySql parameter in my.ini:

```
log_queries_not_using_indexes = 1
log_slow_admin_statements = 1
slow_query_log = 1
long_query_time = 1
```

I haven't got any slow queries (execution time greater than 1 sec), but I have a lot of queries logged as joined query with missing index. One of them, for example, is:

```
SELECT `t_d`.`entity_id`, `t_d`.`attribute_id`, `t_d`.`value` AS `default_value`, `t_s`.`value` AS `store_value`, IF(t_s.value_id IS NULL, t_d.value, t_s.value) AS `value` 
 FROM `catalog_product_entity_text` AS `t_d`
 LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_text` AS `t_s` ON t_s.attribute_id = t_d.attribute_id AND t_s.entity_id = t_d.entity_id AND t_s.store_id = 1 WHERE (t_d.entity_type_id = 4) AND (t_d.entity_id IN (459, 444, 455, 450, 449, 458, 454, 443, 453)) AND (t_d.attribute_id IN ('73')) AND (t_d.store_id = 0) 
UNION ALL SELECT `t_d`.`entity_id`, `t_d`.`attribute_id`, `t_d`.`value` AS `default_value`, `t_s`.`value` AS `store_value`, IF(t_s.value_id IS NULL, t_d.value, t_s.value) AS `value` 
 FROM `catalog_product_entity_decimal` AS `t_d`
 LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_decimal` AS `t_s` ON t_s.attribute_id = t_d.attribute_id AND t_s.entity_id = t_d.entity_id AND t_s.store_id = 1 WHERE (t_d.entity_type_id = 4) AND (t_d.entity_id IN (459, 444, 455, 450, 449, 458, 454, 443, 453)) AND (t_d.attribute_id IN ('76', '80', '120')) AND (t_d.store_id = 0) 
UNION ALL SELECT `t_d`.`entity_id`, `t_d`.`attribute_id`, `t_d`.`value` AS `default_value`, `t_s`.`value` AS `store_value`, IF(t_s.value_id IS NULL, t_d.value, t_s.value) AS `value` 
 FROM `catalog_product_entity_datetime` AS `t_d`
 LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_datetime` AS `t_s` ON t_s.attribute_id = t_d.attribute_id AND t_s.entity_id = t_d.entity_id AND t_s.store_id = 1 WHERE (t_d.entity_type_id = 4) AND (t_d.entity_id IN (459, 444, 455, 450, 449, 458, 454, 443, 453)) AND (t_d.attribute_id IN ('77', '78', '93', '94')) AND (t_d.store_id = 0) 
UNION ALL SELECT `t_d`.`entity_id`, `t_d`.`attribute_id`, `t_d`.`value` AS `default_value`, `t_s`.`value` AS `store_value`, IF(t_s.value_id IS NULL, t_d.value, t_s.value) AS `value` 
 FROM `catalog_product_entity_varchar` AS `t_d`
 LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_varchar` AS `t_s` ON t_s.attribute_id = t_d.attribute_id AND t_s.entity_id = t_d.entity_id AND t_s.store_id = 1 WHERE (t_d.entity_type_id = 4) AND (t_d.entity_id IN (459, 444, 455, 450, 449, 458, 454, 443, 453)) AND (t_d.attribute_id IN ('86', '87', '97', '112', '113', '114', '118', '119', '176')) AND (t_d.store_id = 0) 
UNION ALL SELECT `t_d`.`entity_id`, `t_d`.`attribute_id`, `t_d`.`value` AS `default_value`, `t_s`.`value` AS `store_value`, IF(t_s.value_id IS NULL, t_d.value, t_s.value) AS `value` 
 FROM `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `t_d`
 LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `t_s` ON t_s.attribute_id = t_d.attribute_id AND t_s.entity_id = t_d.entity_id AND t_s.store_id = 1 WHERE (t_d.entity_type_id = 4) AND (t_d.entity_id IN (459, 444, 455, 450, 449, 458, 454, 443, 453)) AND (t_d.attribute_id IN ('96', '121', '123', '125', '126', '127', '128', '131', '192', '193')) AND (t_d.store_id = 0);
```

If I check the table, the index is there... so it is not clear why MySql is logging the query as not indexed, also in Phpmyadmin I have notice about too many query not using indexes.

This is the DESCRIBE output:
[Describe Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ejiiv.png)

I've tried OPTIMIZE TABLE, but the non indexed query are still logged.

Any suggestion on how repare the issue?

Thanks.

Comment: which index in particular does it think is missing? what is the actual result of DESCRIBE?

Comment: Hi, I've edited the post to add the DESCRIBE Output image, you can see the explain plan genereted by phpmyadmin.

Comment: @FilippoScifo  If you make 'long_query_time' = 5000 seconds you will be focused on log_queries_not_using_indexes rather than all the clutter related to a one second limit.

Answer (score 1):

I dislike `log_queries_not_using_indexes = 1` for the reason you found -- It clutters the slowlog because the entries may not be worth noting.

The one excuse for the setting is when you are starting a project, and the tables are still small.  You might have forgetting to add a suitable index to a table that will eventually grow.  For that, I would turn it on for a day, then review the output, add missing indexes, then leave it off forever.

For that query, I would have

```
 t_d:  INDEX(entity_type_id, store_id, attribute_id, entity_id)
 t_s:  INDEX(entity_type_id, store_id)
```

`entity_type_id` and `store_id` can be swapped, but I doubt if it matters.

`OPTIMIZE TABLE` is unlikely to affect index usage.  If the tables are InnoDB (which they should be), you will probably never benefit from `OPTIMIZE TABLE`.

Oh, yuck!  4 tables holding 4 different datatypes.  You will be in trouble as the data grows.  EAV is bad; you made it worse.